# React Native: Network request failed

Tags: react-native

I'm facing a very strange issue:

I try to fetch in a react native application. On a physical iPhone everything works fine, on the simulator I get the error "Network request failed".

The API is https and I already changed the Info.plist to allow NSAllowsArbitraryLoads.

```
var url = requestedURL; // its https

fetch(url)
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((data) =>
    this.setState({ coordinates: data.features[0].geometry.coordinates })
  )
  .catch((err) => console.log(err));
```

Info.plist:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>
        <key>localhost</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
            <true/>
        </dict>
    </dict>
    <key>geoapify.com</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
        <true/>
        <key>NSTemporaryExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
        <true/>
        <key>NSTemporaryExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
        <string>TLSv1.1</string>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

I suggest it has to do with certificates or something.

Comment: Is the requestedURL domain geoapify.com?

Comment: yes it is, api.geoapify.com

Answer (score 0):

Try one of the following ways

**Solution # 1**

Adding 'Content-type': 'application/json' to headers

```
headers: {
  Authorization: token,
  'Content-type': 'application/json',
  /** rest of headers... */
}
```

**Solution # 2**

if you using localhost just change it :

```
from :http://localhost:3030 to :http://10.0.2.2:3030
```

**Solution # 3**

Add `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"` line in AndroidManifest.xml.